# Access to IMAP Inbox in JavaMail with defaultFolder() results in "Bad folder name"

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to cast `javax.mail.Folder` to `IMAPFolder`?

When casting in Netbeans, there was no error. Until the next line where I tried to open the folder

```
                    IMAPFolder ff = (IMAPFolder) store.getDefaultFolder();                        
                    ff.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

I get BAD folder name on the logs:

> [Thread-4] ERROR com.mansueli.mailtester.IMAPController - ERRORjavax.mail.MessagingException: A11 BAD [CLIENTBUG] SELECT Bad folder name. sc=Ttg5C13MBa61_091355_17p;
>     nested exception is:
>       com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A11 BAD [CLIENTBUG] SELECT Bad folder name. sc=Ttg5C13MBa61_091355_17p
>   [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR com.mansueli.mailtester.IMAPController - ERROR it wasn't possible to connect with IMAP properly
>   ERRORjavax.mail.MessagingException: A11 BAD [CLIENTBUG] SELECT Bad folder name. sc=Ttg5C13MBa61_091355_17p;
>     nested exception is:
>       com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A11 BAD [CLIENTBUG] SELECT Bad folder name. sc=Ttg5C13MBa61_091355_17p
>   A11 BAD [CLIENTBUG] SELECT Bad folder name. sc=Ttg5C13MBa61_091355_17p

I want to open it as an IMAP folder but only have the store.

`Store store = session.getStore(imapstore);`

Comment: You'll probably get the same error without casting... If the cast hadn't been possible, you would have received a `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defaultFolder()` is not yet the inbox.

Try this instead::

```
 IMAPFolder ff = (IMAPFolder) store.getDefaultFolder().getFolder("inbox");                        
 ff.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

Good Luck!